# Bootstrap panels not displaying body text

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason my bootstrap panels won't show the body text. I have set up all my elements via DOM Manipulation.

My panel header text displays properly, however my body text doesn't show up.

I also noticed that the bootstrap panel body content does not have any elements, just lines of text.

I have tried to add text elements to it but so far nothing has been working. Here is my code:

**JS**

```
var searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
searchButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var term = document.getElementById('term').value;
 var matched = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < hotelRooms.length; i++) {
   if (hotelRooms[i].hotel.indexOf(term) !== -1) {
     matched.push(hotelRooms[i]);
   }
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < matched.length; i++) {

   var roomResults = document.createElement('div');
   roomResults.setAttribute('id', 'results');
   roomResults.setAttribute('class', 'result-style');

   var resultsArea = document.getElementById('results-area');
       console.log(matched[i]);

   var panelDefault = document.createElement('div');
   panelDefault.setAttribute('class', 'panel-default');

   var panelHeading = document.createElement('div');
   panelHeading.setAttribute('class', 'panel-heading');

   var panelBody = document.createElement('div');
   panelBody.setAttribute('class', 'panel-body');

   var name = document.createElement('h3'); // Hotel Name
   name.setAttribute('class', 'hotel-name');
   name.textContent = matched[i].hotel;

   var price = document.createElement('div'); // Room Price
   price.setAttribute('class', 'room-price');
   price.textContent = matched[i].price;

   roomResults.appendChild(panelDefault);
   panelDefault.appendChild(panelHeading);
   panelHeading.appendChild(name);
   panelBody.appendChild(price);

   resultsArea.appendChild(roomResults);
 }
 });
```

Comment: I have updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never appending `panelBody` to `panelDefault`.

```
....
roomResults.appendChild(panelDefault);
panelDefault.appendChild(panelHeading);
panelHeading.appendChild(name);
panelBody.appendChild(price);
panelDefault.appendChild(panelBody);
....
```

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed this thank you so much it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You have just created a `div`, you need to append it to the `body` tag `document.body.appendChild(size)`

```
var size = document.createElement('div');
size.setAttribute('class', 'room-size');
size.textContent ="hello"
document.body.appendChild(size)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I believe I have not explained in detail. I have different objects and all are properly set up but only the header shows. I have already appended my elements together but my body text does not show up.

Comment: Share some more code or more info, we can not help you with this amount of information.